# Web Test framework for Mobile as well as Server browsers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, test-framework

Is there any framework available where I can write single set of test code for both Server browsers as well as Mobile browsers.

eg. test.py runs with Chrome on Android as well as Windows

I am planning to use browserstack for my testing until I figure out the infrastructure handling is possible with browserstack or not.

Please help me figure out a way for deciding over the infrastructure as well.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you will ever be able to use the same code for testing a web app and its mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [TestCafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/). It's an open source project.

TestCafe allows to run tests on desktop and mobile browsers without any additional installations and plugins.

Here you can see how easy to run tests on a mobile phone with TestCafe: https://twitter.com/DXTestCafe/status/804368394569052160.

Also it's easy to setup testing on mobile browsers in a cloud service (like BrowserStack or Saucelabs). For example you can find the "testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs" plugin on GitHub to run tests on Saucelabs out-of-the box.

Comment: Not sure why, but when I run a test with Testcafe, the login takes more than 25-30 seconds to load the home page. This doesn't happen with Selenium Webdriver, it loads the home page after login in less than 10-15 seconds on a decent network.

Comment: It can be different reasons. It would be very helpful if you provide your tested page url. I'll check this behavior. Usually, TestCafe doesn't slow down page loading so much

Answer (score 0):

Selenium + Appium should be able to cover what you need to be done. To share code however, you'll need use a mobile browser (Chrome or Safari) or have an app that uses webviews that are the same as the browser version.

The Selenium bindings will handle driving the automation for the browsers. By itself, you could test the desktop browser with a normal size screen, as well as a mobile size, and test various browsers as well (Chrome, Firefox, etc).

Appium will allow you to open the browser (or app) on the mobile device or simulator, and if the web view is the same as the browser, the same locator strategies you used with the desktop browsers and Selenium will work with Appium as well (Appium extends the Selenium spec with browser capabilities).

If you code the framework using the Selenium Grid, you can then almost drop replace a remote managed grid setup (via Saucelabs or Browserstack) to run the browsers for you (otherwise you'd need to setup a local grid or run the tests with a local Selenium server set up)

Answer (score 0):

All this is quite possible

> framework available where I can write single set of test code for both Server browsers as well as Mobile browsers

We have build it in our company, since we have a vast diversity of different platforms and browsers to support.

We use combination of Selenium based frameworks on NodeJS

- webdriverIO
- cucumberJS
- appium

... etc.

The main concept we try to follow is JAVA's [WORA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere). To achieve all this you need a good understanding of [DSL](http://martinfowler.com/dsl.html)s, [Application driver layer](http://continuousdev.com/2015/08/successful-automated-acceptance-tests/) and design patterns (e.g. [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)).

[image]

It is not that hard to put all this together, since Selenium supports pretty much every binding you need. Just pick the language you are most comfortable with and use it.